# Are there any nonlinear crystals or other transparent materials that can produce anti-Stokes, phase matched, frequency shift of laser light?

Tags: visible-light, laser, crystals, non-linear-optics, photonics

While some nonlinear crystals can convert incoming laser light into harmonics, thus for example doubling the light frequency, are there any crystals or other transparent materials that can reduce the frequency of laser light while matching the phase or maintaining a stable phase shift.

Comment: Optical parametric oscillators and amplifiers.